# memory overflow in Python using pymc

Tags: python, pymc, mcmc

Following apparently simple code for MCMC in Python causes a huge memory usage (>15GB) even though I use pickle backend. This happens whenever I use arrays of observed variables in pymc. Any idea on why this is happening?

```
import pymc as pymc
import numpy as np

N = 17
numC = 5

A = np.zeros([N,N])
A[0:numC, :] = 1
A[:, 0:numC] = 1

C = pymc.Beta('C', alpha=0.5, beta=0.5, size=N)

@pymc.deterministic(dtype=float)
def q(_C=C):
    Q = np.zeros([N,N])
    for i in range(0,N-1):
        for j in range(i+1, N):
            Q[i, j] = Q[j, i] = C[i] + C[j] - C[i]*C[j]

    return Q

obs = []
for i in range(0,N-1):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        o = pymc.Bernoulli('A%d%d'%(i,j), p=q[i,j], value=A[i,j], observed=True)
        obs.append(o)

model = pymc.Model([C, q] + obs)

mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model, db='pickle', dbname='abc.pickle')
mcmc.sample(10000, burn=5000, thin=5)
mcmc.db.close()
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. I've posted on Github (as that appears to be the best place to seek support) but haven't had any luck. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: Just a remark, in your q function you named the parameter _C but then use C

Answer (score 0):

1. from personal experience, pickle can be extremely fat in memory with large objects, and it usually inflates and grows without releasing memory as I've seen.
2. can try to use [memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to check where the memory growth occurs, it allows decorating functions in a way to see a nice plotted graph of the memory growing during their execution.